# Typesetting actuarial term-certain symbol in pure TeX/MathJax

Tags: mathjax

I have used the following code for a while to typeset the acturial symbol for a term certain, which is the half-box symbol around the n in this image:

[Link to Wikipedia example image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Actuarial_notation.svg)

[Link to page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuarial_notation)

```
\def \termcertain #1% {% {\setbox 0 = \hbox {$\scriptstyle #1$}% \dimen 0 = \ht 0 
\advance \dimen 0 by 1,0 pt \ht 0 = \dimen 0 \dimen 0 = \dp 0 \advance \dimen 0 by 1,50 pt 
\dp 0 = \dimen 0 \vbox {\hrule \hbox {\box 0 \vrule }}% }% }
```

Usage:

```
a_\termcertain{n}
```

I got to this code by, frankly, taking something that half worked, combining it with something else that half worked, and poking it with a stick until it met my needs.

I'd now like to use this code on a forum that uses MathJax.  As is, it doesn't work, and I'm not sure why, but I presume it is using features that are not available in the Mathjax environment.

Two questions:

1. How do I fix this to work with MathJax?
2. How do I configure the Mathjax installation to make \termcertain available to users?

Comment: Note that mathjax does not use TeX so questions are off topic for here. The mathml is `<menclose notation="actuarial"><mi>n</mi></menclose>` MathJax exposes this with a custom macro: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#enclose

Comment: @David Sorry - I think I'm missing somethign here. Yes, the underlying engine is not TeX but the input language (by and large) is, which is what my question concerns.  Where would be a better place?  <menclose> is an ideal solution but the forum I'm using doesn't have support for MathML (corporations, beauracracy, etc, etc).

Comment: the mathjax help group in google groups or within stackexchange so tag mathjax If you click on the mathjax tag under your question you get links to both of those) The page I linked to in my question shows the mathjax specific _tex-like_ syntax for mathml features not in the normal tex packages. so it will be something like `\enclose[actuarial]{n}` As you see the input language and the engine are interrelated, that syntax doesn't (by default) work in standard latex.

Comment: While [tag:MathJax] uses LaTeX syntax, it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic for this site. You might try insteead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.